# Loaded Solar cell simulation on Proteus

Tags: power-supply, current, solar-cell, simulation, proteus

does anyone know how to simulate a solar cell with a load like an LED or a lamp or a motor or something-not just a load in the form of resistance-on Proteus?I want it work the way a normal photo-voltaic cell works ie:when light hits it, it converts the light to electric current without any external power source.How can I do this?

Comment: You can't simulate light on Proteus..... You'll just have to put in a current source and change the output

Comment: A current source in parallel with a silicon diode (forward biased by the current source) is pretty close to a solar cell. Set the current proportional to the illumination ... I've seen "quantum efficiency" figures around 0.5A/Watt but check the datasheet for your cell.

Comment: @MCG What do you mean, I can't simulate light on Proteus? If I can't simulate light how do I know the cell works with any type of load. And do you know any other software which is easy to use and on which you can do simulations like these easily?I tried the parallel combination of current source, diode, resistance in series with a another resistance. But with a load and with light falling on it it doesn't work, unless I just simply increase the value of the current source.

Comment: Even if Proteus has a solar cell model on it, which I believe it does not, it doesn't have a changeable light source that will be able to simulate light. As far as I know, you won't be able to simulate a solar cell on software that I know of. Maybe there is some out there, but not on proteus, you'll have to substitue a current source in for it and check your solar cell datasheet

Comment: So if I want to make a solar cell with a working load I have to do it physically, I can't do it virtually,to see if my circuits works or not. After all that's what most of the electronics softwares are there for.What about Multisim?